# Hg: see timestamp of pull/push relative to upstream

Tags: mercurial

The `hg history` command shows me results in the following format:

```
changeset:   1:000000000000
user:        somebody
date:        Fri Jun 06 22:38:10 2014 +0000
summary:     Do something clever.
```

The "date" seen above defaults to using the time the revision was committed to its original repository.  Is there a parameter I can give it to get the time it was pushed to the upstream, or pulled to my local repository, instead?  Both `hg help history` and Google ({hg history timestamps}, {hg config revision timestamps}, {hg revision timestamps local}, ...) are drawing a blank for me.

(Alternatively, is there any other way for me to quickly eyeball the history and see what revisions were done in a particular timeframe, when one of the committers has a computer clock which is always off but not consistently by the same amount?)

Answer (score -3):

You can select changesets by users and date using [revsets](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets) (see also `hg help dates` for how dates are formatted):

```
hg log -r "user(soandso) AND date('2014-05-21 to 2014-05-30')
```

The dates will still be the commit dates. I'm not sure if or where any other dates are stored.

Comment: To those who assume this doesn't answer the question and are downvoting -- this answer answers the "Alternatively,..." part of the question.